# Send form data via php?

Tags: php, html

The form action is "" because it all uses the same page. Is there anyway the form can submit on the same page without refreshing?

PHP:

```
<?php 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $to="josue.espinosa@mtchs.org";
    $subject="Tech Muffins Contact";
    $message="Name:      ".$_REQUEST['name']."\n\nEmail:      ".$_REQUEST['email']."\n\nMessage: ".$_REQUEST['message'];
    $from = "donotreply@techmuffins.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="contactform" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" autofocus required>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="message" required></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Without refresh, you would have to perform some jquery/ajax requests to insert/run the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  'your.php' to yours

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#contactform").submit( function () {    
                  $.post(
                   'your.php', 
                    $(this).serialize(),
                    function(data){
                      //if you have a div to show result (with id=results)
                      $("#results").html(data)
                   //if sucess hide the form as $("#contactform").hide()
                  // or .fadeOut() 
                    }
                  );
                  return false;   
                });   
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this without refreshing, you'll usually handle this through Ajax. There exists javascript functions for this. Here's an example (using jQuery):

```
var frm = $(document.myform);
var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());
```